# how to access elements in a 2D Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to read string variables from a single array (or more precisely from *an array of arrays of strings*, as [clarified in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41600763/2348597)) in Swift. The following reads the entire array.

```
    var array = [["W", "X", "Y", "Z"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
    print(array[0],array[1])
```

How do I read a pair of variables, e.g. "X" and "D" ?

Comment: keithbhunter's explanation let me see why the original wording might have been a problem. I edited the question so it does not confuse SO users

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array` is an array of arrays of strings. Or, type `Array<Array<String>>`. `array[0]` will return the first element of the array, which is an array of strings, or `Array<String>`. Which means you must then access another single element of that array. Step by step, the code would look like this:

```
let array = [["W", "X", "Y", "Z"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]

let firstArray = array[0]  // ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
let X = firstArray[1]  // "X"

let secondArray = array[1]  // ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
let D = secondArray[3]  // "D"
```

The short version looks like this:

```
print(array[0][1], array[1][3])  // "X D"
```

Comment: That's really clear. It's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Just provide an index of the first level, and then the second level.

```
print(array[1][3])
```

You can also iterate over arrays of multiple levels in this way

```
for subarray in array {
    for element in subarray {
        print(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only prints the second level

Comment: Well, you only have strings in your two subarrays @Greg.  Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: sorry about the lack of clarity

Answer (score 1):

```
array[0][0] // "W"
array[0][1] // "X"
array[0][2] // "Y"
array[1][0] // "A"
```

I guess you now get it! ;)

PS: With a nested for you can have:

```
for i in 0...3 {
    for j in 0...3 {
        print(array[i][j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `zip` an array of indices (one for each inner array) with the arrays of arrays (`array`), and use a `map` call on this zipped sequence to construct an array with one elements from each inner array. E.g.

```
let array = [["W", "X", "Y", "Z"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
let innerIdxs = [1, 3]

let innerElements = zip(array, innerIdxs).map { $0[$1] }
print(innerElements) // ["X", "D"]
```

Just note that this will lead to a runtime exception due to index out of bounds in case any of the indices in the `innerIdxs` array exceed the number of elements - 1 (in the corresponding inner array). A safer approach would be validating the index prior to using it, e.g.:

```
let innerElements = zip(array, innerIdxs)
    .map { 0..<$0.count ~= $1 ? $0[$1] : "invalid index" }
```

which would yield the following `innerElements` given the following few examples of `innerIdxs` arrays:

```
let innerIdxs = [4, 3] 
    // ... -> innerElements = ["invalid index", "D"]

let innerIdxs = [2, -1] 
    // ... -> innerElements = ["Y", "invalid index"]
```