# Access to array inside array

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var array = [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        ["q", "w", "e"],
        ["p", "h", "j"],
        ["z", "r", "m"]
]
```

How can I access 4. line 1. letter "z" ?

Comment: A good place to learn about arrays is the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) book

Comment: Look at this question, [How to access elements in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600670/how-to-access-elements-in-a-2d-array-in-swift)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the help! I appreciate that. Next time i wanna solve my array problem is this 2 links coming for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var z = array[3][0]
```

This gets the 1st element (index 0) in the 4th array (index 3).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: Thanks for help! I trying to do array[3[0]] and result is nothing.

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: Technically this gets the 1st element from the 4th array. Don't mix ordinals with indexing offsets.